# Read file and write/sort in array of struct

Tags: c, file, struct

I am trying to write a program which reads a file, stores the data in an array of struct, calculates volume and is written to a new file sorted by volume. The program compiles and writes to the new file, but it is not sorting by volume and weight prints 0.000000 for each weight.

**EDIT: Everything works except sorting by volume**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159265

struct cylinder {
    double radius;
    double height;
    double weight;
    double volume;
};

void selection_sort(struct cylinder my_cylinders[], int n);

int main() {
    FILE *cFileIn, *cFileOut;
    double radius, height, weight, volume;

    struct cylinder my_cylinders[100];

    cFileIn = fopen("cylinders.txt", "r");
    if (cFileIn == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    cFileOut = fopen("sorted_cylinders.txt", "w");
    if (cFileOut == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(cFileOut, "#    Radius           Height          Volume          Weight\n");

    int i, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
        while (fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height, &volume, &weight) != EOF) {
            my_cylinders[counter].radius = radius;
            my_cylinders[counter].height = height;
            my_cylinders[counter].volume = volume;
            my_cylinders[counter].weight = weight;

            volume = PI * radius * radius * height; 
            fprintf(cFileOut, "%-d\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t   %-12.6lf\t \n", 
                    counter, radius, height, volume, weight);
            counter++;      
        }
    }

    selection_sort(my_cylinders, counter);
    printf("File sorted_cylinders.txt written \n");

    fclose(cFileIn);
    fclose(cFileOut);
    return 0;
}

void selection_sort(struct cylinder my_cylinders[], int n) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, min;
    struct cylinder temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (my_cylinders[j].volume < my_cylinders[min].volume) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        temp = my_cylinders[i];
        my_cylinders[i] = my_cylinders[min];
        my_cylinders[min] = temp;
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
#    Radius           Height          Volume          Weight
0     2.400000        12.000000       217.146884       15.000000    
1     18.200000       14.200000       14776.820321     25.900000    
2     22.800000       10.600000       17311.130546     4.500000     
3     3.500000        2.500000        96.211275        15.800000    
4     6.000000        1.000000        113.097335       2.900000     
5     21.000000       1.000000        1385.442359      100.000000
```

Comment: then debug `selection_sort` or add prints...

Comment: Why do you calculate the volume after reading the volume from the file?

Comment: Also, it must be after sorting to write to the file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the volume is not read but calculated and added to the new file. The first file only has radius, height and weight. I will move sort before writting. Thanks

Comment: So `fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height, &volume, &weight)` --> `fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height, &weight) `

Comment: I moved the sort call before writing, but still does not sort and weight is still coming up as 0.000000.

Comment: Delete `volume` items from `fscanf`.

Comment: And yes, thanks! I see that extra volume. So I have the correct weights showing up now, just need to sort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149292/discussion-between-bambaera-and-bluepixy).

Comment: After reading all the records, sort them then write them out.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, That is what I am having trouble with figuring out. Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: You are trying to sort before loading records.

Comment: Your output would be better readable if you omitted the `-` from the `%-12.6f` conversion specifications.  It would right-align the numbers in the more orthodox way that tables of numbers are usually printed.  Your output format includes tabs; your header output does not.  That's bad.  The header and the content lines should agree better.  You could use `%12s` to right align words, and fix up the tabs and spaces too.

Comment: when calling the function: `fscanf()`, there are other problem returns besides `EOF`  There is only one return value that indicates success.  That return value is a count of the number of successful input/format conversions matching the number of input/format specifications in the `format` string.  So this line: `while (fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height, &volume, &weight) != EOF) ` should be: `while (fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &radius, &height, &volume, &weight) == 4)`

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/ILfQUx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

- why do you have 2 nested loops to read the file?
- you may read beyond the end of the array if there are more than 100 entries in the file.
- You should test that the return value of `fscanf()` is the number of expected conversions, not that it is different from `EOF`.  If invalid input is present in the file, `fscanf()` will keep returning `0`, not `EOF`.
- you should not read the volume from the input file, since it is not present.
- you should use a more precise value of PI: unfortunately `M_PI` is not always defined in `<math.h>` because the C Standard does not mandate it. Use this:

  ```
  #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
  ```
- The algorithm in selection sort is flawed.  Use `qsort` with a comparison function.
- You write the output file before sorting the data.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

struct cylinder {
    double radius;
    double height;
    double weight;
    double volume;
};

int cylinder_cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    /* sort cylinders by increasing volume */
    const struct cylinder *c1 = p1;
    const struct cylinder *c2 = p2;
    return (c1->volume > c2->volume) - (c1->volume < c2->volume);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *cFileIn, *cFileOut;
    double radius, height, weight, volume;

    struct cylinder my_cylinders[100];

    cFileIn = fopen("cylinders.txt", "r");
    if (cFileIn == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    cFileOut = fopen("sorted_cylinders.txt", "w");
    if (cFileOut == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file \n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i, counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++) {
        /* read value from the file, ignoring the volume */ 
        if (fscanf(cFileIn, "%lf, %lf, %lf",
                   &radius, &height, &weight) == 3) {
            my_cylinders[i].radius = radius;
            my_cylinders[i].height = height;
            my_cylinders[i].weight = weight;
            my_cylinders[i].volume = M_PI * radius * radius * height;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(cFileIn);

    qsort(my_cylinders, counter, sizeof(*my_cylinders), cylinder_cmp);

    fprintf(cFileOut, "#    Radius           Height          Volume          Weight\n");

    for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {   
        fprintf(cFileOut, "%-d\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t  %-12.6lf\t   %-12.6lf\n", 
                 counter,
                 my_cylinders[counter].radius,
                 my_cylinders[counter].height,
                 my_cylinders[counter].volume,
                 my_cylinders[counter].weight);
    }
    fclose(cFileOut);
    printf("File sorted_cylinders.txt written\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from comments _the volume is not read_ .. _Delete volume items from fscanf._ .. _I see that extra volume. So I have the correct weights showing up now_ So input file has 3 field per line. (and See revisions 4)

Comment: Also "M_PI defined in <math.h>" : C standard doesn't defined `M_PI`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: yes it is a pity the C Standard does not mandate it. So many programmers resort to approximate definitions.